# In Altium how do you increase the trace width from a Pour to GND Vias and Pads?

Tags: pcb-design, altium, trace

In my PCB layout I have a ground power connector and several pads where I would like thick traces to connect to the ground plane.

When I use the polygon pour feature, it will connect these with 4 traces. How do I increase this width? There is also an LED with an isolated thermal pad, which ideally would have no gap at all. The image below show what I mean.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short Answer: Design Rules

Hit D-R (design rules):

### "No Gap At All"

Set the polygon connect type to "Direct"

### "Increase the width"

Set the spoke width in the polygon connect rule

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I believe the conductor width is what your trying to increase. It is in the Design Rules.